# Generic lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, generics, salesfront-reference-architecture

I want to create a related list with LWC that i can use for all object.
Can someone help me with any ideato solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this question is too broad for this site. If you've made an attempt to do this already, you should [edit] your question to include that (and describe a specific thing you are stuck on). If you're new to Salesforce (or new to Lightning Web Components), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[Enhanced Lightning Grid](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EVK8iUAH) (Sortable datagrid), a free appExchange provides generic Aura component to build customized related list with additional features.

> The Enhanced Lightning Grid component allows you to create a richer related list capability with support for sorting, filtering and pagination of data. Sort and filter on any column for rapid access to the record you are looking for.

The source code is available on GitHub repo so you can adapt the solution and build your own component in **LWC**
https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/EnhancedLightningGrid